# Is there "@Deprecated" annotation for methods in .aidl files?

Tags: methods, deprecated, aidl

Is there a corresponding "@Deprecated" annotation-syntax for methods in .aidl files?
I want to mark a method as deprecated, add a new method and promote the use of that one instead, while still maintaining backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find example on next URL: [@Deprecated in .aidl](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/jb-mr0-release/core/java/android/app/INotificationManager.aidl)

Example from mentioned URL:

```
/** @deprecated use {@link #enqueueNotificationWithTag} instead */
void enqueueNotification(String pkg, int id, in Notification notification, inout int[] idReceived);

/** @deprecated use {@link #cancelNotificationWithTag} instead */
void cancelNotification(String pkg, int id);
```